Why my GPO isn't applied?
I have an active directory domain, and I'm trying to setup FSLogix on "Eleves" (students) profile, but the gpo doesn't apply on the client where the student logged in. I've made another gpo to check if it works (disable-menu-contextuel-demarrer), and everything's fine with this lasts one, it shows up when I type gpresult /R on the  client. I don't understand because it is linked at the same group, the same way...
. What I have done so far :

My AD DS and file server are the same machine
My gpo is configured and linked to "Eleves"
the share ProfilsFSLogix is setup and RW accessible from students when they log into the domain.
gpupdate /Force doesn't solve my problem
FSLogix is installed on the client

What I'm doing wrong, what i've forgotten ?



Is this a user or computer policy? I can't determine that from the information you've given at this point.

all the parameters in U_FSLogix are in "computer configuration, strategy, administration models (admx files), FSLogix". U_FSLogix is applied on Eleve OU, containing users profiles.

So, its a computer configuration then, which means that it is applied at computer level, and as such, you need to ensure that the GPO is also applied to the computers, not just the user. And if the user is not local administrator, an administrator needs to do the gpupdate, or reboot the computer. (the gpupdate is purely for testing)

Ok I'm clearly missing something...

The container "computers" is not here on the first picture, so I can't do that
If I apply the gpo on Eleves and container "computers", when the rule is applied ? AND or OR ?


And. You also link the GPO object to the container Computers. Alternatively, link the GPO to a higher level that hits both computers and users. You may have to do something to filter out computers you don't want to target, such as using wmi filters or using a security group that also contains the computers.

if i add the computer in the Eleve OU it works perfectly, so thx :). You solved my problem ! feel free to answer if you want me to validate it

After a bit of comment exchange, the problem was found.
When you apply a GPO, there are two levels to apply it to. Computers and Users.
A GPO object has both sections in one object, and depending on what you apply the GPO to, none, one or both will be applied.
You had setup the GPO to apply to users, but the setting was actually in computers. This means you also have to apply the GPO to computers for it to run on a computer.
The biggest difference is that GPO's that apply to users don't need special rights, but computer policies do use administrative rights to be run. They are run as system as the computer boots before the user logs in, but if you run a Command Prompt as admin, and run gpupdate there, they will run also.
